# the multiple spacing between the words with Reg Expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this Reg exp

```
[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\-\s][a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

It allows one space between the words, how can I make this reg exp to accept multiple spaces between the words and spaces after the last word and before the first word.If the user's enters the text with multiple blank spaces how can I trim it to one blank space.

Comment: You don't need to escape characters between `[]`, so it can be `[',.-\s]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regexp: `[a-zA-Z]+((\s*[',.-]?\s*[a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$`

Comment: eg: van der wall..this will pass                                             van  der   wall this will fails as the blank spaces are more than one..i need a exp which will pass above

Comment: @user1016740, it is strange but your example works for me. Just tested on regexpal.com `van der wall` and `van              der   wall` with many spaces, both pass

Comment: yes it worked..but when user enter just blank spaces,,still its passing, how to make it fail if they doesn't enter anything

Comment: @user1016740, `[a-zA-Z]+` in the begin doesn't allow empty strings with only spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all `\s+` with a single space before matching. That handles the trimming and matching at the same time, for no extra cost.

Comment: this is how it should be [a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\-\s+][a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$

Comment: @user1016740: No, keep that the same. Just run a replacement on the string before matching it against that pattern.

Comment: if the user enters a string with multiple spaces the validation fails right, I need if the user enters the string with multiple spaces it should work

Comment: can you please modify the exp with your suggestion.

Comment: @user1016740: It is a separate regular expression. The one you posted is not involved. Perform the space replacement first, and then do the matching. They are not in the same expression.